# ActiveMQ Vulnerability - CVE-2023-46604

Tags: content-delivery, activemq

Description:

Apache ActiveMQ is vulnerable to Remote Code Execution.The vulnerability may allow a remote attacker with network access to a broker to run arbitrary shell commands by manipulating serialized class types in the OpenWire protocol to cause the broker to instantiate any class on the classpath.

Comment: What's the actual question here? This seems to just be the same information that's available from Apache and any of the CVE aggregator sites.

Answer (score 1):

Affected versions:

- Apache ActiveMQ 5.18.0 before 5.18.3
- Apache ActiveMQ 5.17.0 before 5.17.6
- Apache ActiveMQ 5.16.0 before 5.16.7
- Apache ActiveMQ before 5.15.16
- Apache ActiveMQ Legacy OpenWire Module 5.18.0 before 5.18.3
- Apache ActiveMQ Legacy OpenWire Module 5.17.0 before 5.17.6
- Apache ActiveMQ Legacy OpenWire Module 5.16.0 before 5.16.7
- Apache ActiveMQ Legacy OpenWire Module 5.8.0 before 5.15.16

Description:

Apache ActiveMQ is vulnerable to Remote Code Execution.The vulnerability may allow a remote attacker with network access to a broker to run arbitrary shell commands by manipulating serialized class types in the OpenWire protocol to cause the broker to instantiate any class on the classpath.

Users are recommended to upgrade to version 5.15.16, 5.16.7, 5.17.6, or 5.18.3, which fixes this issue.

This issue is being tracked as AMQ-9370

References:

https://activemq.apache.org/security-advisories.data/CVE-2023-46604
https://activemq.apache.org/
https://www.cve.org/CVERecord?id=CVE-2023-46604
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-9370